# Python - Remove Logs with a Timestamp

Tags: python-3.x, logging

In the process of creating a log system for a python script that I have created, I want to clean up the data weekly, but Im not sure the best way to proceed. Below is the code I have creating everything I need to actually log items.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('Python Script Logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Create a file handler
handler = logging.FileHandler('My_Test_Log.log')
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Create a logging format
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - Line: %(lineno)d - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

#add the handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.info('-----------------------------')
logger.info('Creating New Entry')
```

What I have is something along the lines of this, but none of the lines are being removed when I call the function. The logic is that it opens the old log file, and open a new file and write to the new one any lines that do not contain the timestamp that I want to remove.

```
def clear_logs():
    date_array = ['2018-06-12']
    with open('My_Test_log.log') as old_file, open('My_New_Test.log', 'w') as new_file:
        for line in old_file:
            if not any(date in line for date in date_array):
                new_file.write(line)
```

Some of the rows in my log file look like so:

```
2018-06-12 15:55:41,554 - Line:144 - ERROR - Error inserting row
2018-06-12 15:55:41,603 - Line:144 - ERROR - Error inserting row
2018-06-13 08:58:54,492 - Line:30 - INFO - -----------------------------
2018-06-13 08:58:54,493 - Line:31 - INFO - Creating New Entry
2018-06-13 08:58:54,493 - Line:205 - WARNING - Invalid argument provided
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering with what I have found to work. Basically the idea behind this is to open a file, read, store then close. Then open again as a write option, and search for the lines of text you are looking for in a line and remove if it is was you have. This will clean up any line that you are looking to remove.

```
my_file = open(log_file, "r")
lines = my_file.readlines()
my_file.close()

my_file = open(log_file, "w")
my_array= ['fill','this','with','what','you','wish','to','remove']

for line in lines:
    for item in my_array:
        if item in line:
            pass
        else:
            my_file.write(line)
my_file.close()
```